# Accepted job offer but now no contact in a week

Tags: software-industry, communication, job-offer

I received an email offering me an internship with a software company. I accepted the offer and they followed up the email asking for my address so they can draft a contract and I gave them my address. It has been a week since this last email and I have heard nothing, two days ago (Monday evening) I sent an email asking a question about the position (and also just in the hopes to get a response so that it would settle my nerves), but they haven't yet replied to that email either.

I want to know if this is normal behaviour and I have nothing to worry about, or if not what should I do? Should I call them? (I have the phone number of the person I have been corresponding with via email as they interviewed me on the phone previously), email HR directly? Just need a little advice as I am new to this whole thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: When is the internship supposed to start?

Answer (score 7):

This is usually not normal, call them up **now**. (actually you should have done it on the 3rd day of silence itself, but better late than never, do it now without any further delay).

Comment: I called and got no answer so left an embarrassingly worried sounding voicemail saying that I'm just checking in and would appreciate a call back.

Comment: @Retsek it would also help if you could call them again in a while...